# Sound issue in device

Tags: iphone, audio

```
NSString *musicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ding" ofType:@"mp3"];
if (musicPath)
{
    if(TapSoud)
    { 
        [TapSoud release];
        TapSoud = nil;
    }
    TapSoud = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath] error:nil];
}

[TapSoud setDelegate:self];
[TapSoud prepareToPlay];
[TapSoud play];


NSString *musicPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"roadrunner" ofType:@"mp3"];
if (musicPath1)
{
    if(MatchSoud)
    { 
        [MatchSoud release];
        MatchSoud = nil;
    }
    MatchSoud = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath1] error:nil];
}

[MatchSoud setDelegate:self];
[MatchSoud prepareToPlay];

NSString *musicPath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Wrong Answer" ofType:@"wav"];
if (musicPath2)
{
    if(WrongMatchSoud)
    { 
        [WrongMatchSoud release];
        WrongMatchSoud = nil;
    }
    WrongMatchSoud = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath2] error:nil];
}

[WrongMatchSoud setDelegate:self];
[WrongMatchSoud prepareToPlay];
```

This code works properly in the simulator, but generates no sound on the device. What is the problem here?

Comment: Why don't you use ARC? It really simplifies things

Comment: The pattern `if (x) { [x release]; x = nil; } x = [something]` can be simplified to `[x release]; x = [something]`. Both the `if (x)` and `x = nil` are redundant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is that the audio files are missing either in the project or at resource copying stage. The simulator stores previously copied resources even if removed from the project until the application is removed completely from the simulator.

Make sure `musicPath`, `musicPath1` and `musicPath2` are not empty and valid.